# Wrong Central Administration link after moving it

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, alternate-access-mapping

I am working on a SharePoint 2016 OnPremise 3 server farm:

- WebFrontEnd
- Application with cache
- Sql

I needed to cahnge the application server, so I added it to the farm and migrated the CA as written in [this](http://sptrac.com/wordpress/?p=1653) post and updated the AAM. Since it did not work I tried to unprovision and provision it without the wizard, using psconfig as mentioned [here](https://sharepointnotes.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/quick-tip-moving-the-central-administration-web-site/). I also checked the [registry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e39780cf-f2b9-4d2d-8c25-02ebcd47994d/sharepoint-30-central-administration-url-change?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy), did not help.
When on the server I click on Start -> SharePoint 2016 Central Administration, it opens the new one and it works.
What am I missing?

Comment: Check IIS Bindings

Comment: Please explain me, don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that When on the server I click on Start -> SharePoint 2016 Central Administration, it opens the new one and it works.

What is the correct URL? And what is the wrong URL?

SharePoint 2016: Managing Central Administration web Application (Provisioning, Unprovisioning):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34220.sharepoint-2016-managing-central-administration-web-application-provisioning-unprovisioning.aspx

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/025c30da-0d5f-4c49-9c4f-c49493b6f75b/moving-central-administration-site-from-one-server-to-another-server-with-in-the-farm?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: I already had seen these posts. 
However, when I say it works, it opens the url of the new server (http:/server02:8005). The wrong one is pointing to the old one (http:/server01:8005).

Comment: It required a restart of both servers. Now everything is fine.